# angularjs data-ng-class not applying the expected css

Tags: angularjs

Html code,

```
<span style='cursor:pointer' data-ng-class='highlightedText:true'>Dheepan raju</span>
```

css,

```
.highlightedText{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Simple code. But the text is not underlined. Did I miss anything? [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0wWyeXSGW7J2mfBXx57?p=preview) is the plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-class takes object as input. And you are passing it as plain text. 
Your code should be

```
 <span style='cursor:pointer' data-ng-class='{highlightedText:true}'>Dheepan raju</span>
```

*Checkout your plnkr, there is angularjs 404 error also. Try changing angularjs source url.*

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4DcfL8TVeSmdjd0crPg?p=preview) is the updated plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class has to be used like this 
`ng-class="{highlightedText:true}"` and I think your angular script has some error, try copying angular CDN.